# Linear Algebra in Games in a 2D space

Tags: math, 2d, linear-algebra, algebra

I am currently teaching myself linear algebra in games and I almost feel ready to use my new-found knowledge in a simple 2D space. I plan on using a math library, with vectors/matrices etc. to represent positions and direction unlike my last game, which was simple enough not to need it.

I just want some clarification on this issue. First, is it valid to express a position in 2D space in 4x4 homogeneous coordinates, like this:

[400, 300, 0, 1]

Here, I am assuming, for simplicity that we are working in a fixed resolution (and in screen space) of 800 x 600, so this should be a point in the middle of the screen.

Is this valid?

Suppose that this position represents the position of the player, if I used a vector, I could represent the direction the player is facing:

[400, 400, 0, 0]

So this vector would represent that the player is facing the bottom of the screen (if we are working in screen space.

Is this valid?

Lastly, if I wanted to rotate the player by 90 degrees, I know I would multiply the vector by a matrix/quarternion, but this is where I get confused. I know that quarternions are more efficient, but I'm not exactly sure how I would go about rotating the direction my player is facing.

Could someone explain the math behind constructing a quarternion and multiplying it by my face vector?

I also heard that OpenGL and D3D represent vectors in a different manner, how does that work? I don't exactly understand it.

I am trying to start getting a handle on basic linear algebra in games before I step into a 3D space in several months.

Comment: Much of your question depends on details of one or another library's implementation.  I'd strongly suggest the best approach might be to pick a "best fit" library, then just start playing with it a bit.  IMHO...

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It always seems to be a good idea to just jump in and start playing around with things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent your position as a 4D coordinate, however, I would recommend using only the dimensions that are needed (i.e. a 2D vector).

The direction is mostly expressed as a vector that starts at the player's position and points in the according direction. So a direction vector of (0,1) would be much easier to handle.
Given that vector you can use a rotation matrix. Quaternions are not really necessary in that case because you don't want to rotate about arbitrary axes. You just want to rotate about the z-axis. You helper library should provide methods to create such matrix and transform the vector with it (transform as a normal).

I am not sure about the difference between the OpenGL's and D3D's representation of the vectors. But I think, it is all about memory usage which should be a thing you don't want to worry about.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response. I was thinking about using a vector of unit-length, and as you said, it would make more sense and be easier to handle that way. Also, thanks for clearing that up about quarternions, i'm just trying to understand the math behind the math library i'm using. This is the whole reason i'm reading through Mathematics for 3D Game Programming by Lengyel. I'm trying to get a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I can not answer all of your questions, but in terms of what is 'valid' or not it all completely depends on if it contains all of the information that you need and it makes sense to you.

Furthermore it is a little strange to have the direction that an object is facing be a non-unit vector. Basically you do not need the information of how long the vector is to figure out the direction they are facing, You simply need to be able to figure out the radians or degrees that they have rotated from 0 degrees or radians. Therefore people usually simply encode the radians or degrees directly as many linear algebra libraries will allow you to do vector math using them.

Comment: I appreciate the response, I'm still working through these ideas. Thanks for the help.